# Android Customize C2DM (Push) Message Display

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

Is there a way to customize the C2DM push message that appears in the Status Bar notifications?

I want to format the message before its rendered in the notification panel like change the font and tweak the message etc.,

Answer (score 1):

The Android documentation on this is unusually good.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html